# Create ContainerAwareCommand in Symfony2 for print data

Tags: php, symfony

I want create ContainerAwareCommand in Symfony2 for print email from my database. I have another class, which consist my data.  I only start, but what i my do next?

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('demo:email:get')
        ->setDescription('Print all emails form db');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $service = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_elastica.finder.site.user.email');
    $output->writeln('<p>%s</p>', $service);
}
```

But in my console, my command does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Follows the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html).

In short, add `execute()` method to the class, get your service from the container, then display the data.

```
   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $service = $this->getContainer()->get('your_service.database_connection');

        $email = // work with $service

        $output->writeln(/*here you render the data*/);
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to get the data without creating a service?

Comment: If I didn't understand what you meant, I'm sure others won't either. Please explain.

Comment: @John Cartwright i update code.
I want get all email from my db, but i can't create service for this

Answer (score 1):

May be you're doing something wrong, check class name, directory name, etc. From the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#automatically-registering-commands):

> To make the console commands available automatically with Symfony,
>   create a **Command** directory inside your bundle and create a PHP file
>   suffixed with **Command.php** for each command that you want to provide.
>   For example, if you want to extend the AppBundle to greet you from the
>   command line, create **GreetCommand.php**